# What's the right way to create one hot encoding?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science

I have the code below to create an encoding. But I feel there's a better way to perform this encoding. Can I get any suggestions preferably using scikit-learn or pandas.

```
"""
total_features = ["male","female", "tall", "short"]
features = ["male", "tall"]
"""
d = dict()
for i in total_features:
    d[i] = 0
for i in features:
    d[i] = 1
final_input = list(d.values())
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

Comment: Can you please provide a solution as to how to go about this task with the code above?

Comment: Your code do not produce one hot encoding. for your example one hot encoding is : `[[1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1]]`

Comment: What's the right way to do this via code?

Comment: Your question has multiple Ambiguities. Do you want One-hot-encoding? or do you want another code for doing your code in another way?

Comment: This is one_hot_encoding. `import pandas as pd` , `pd.get_dummies(["male","female", "tall", "short"])`

Comment: Okay. Well understood. The code above doesn't produce the expected input[final_input]. Can you help me with a better suggestion?

Comment: @TEX what do you want? A better way to do what you already do? Your `final_input` can be produced with: `[1 if x in features else 0 for x in total_features]`. Or something else? Then describe what you want and provide the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

- You can get your `final_input = [1, 0, 1, 0]` with a simple list comprehension:

```py
[1 if x in features else 0 for x in total_features]
```

- If you have your `features` and `total_features` as `pd.Series`:

```py
total_features = pd.Series(total_features)
features = pd.Series(features)
```

you can still use a list comprehenshion, but with a small change:

```py
[1 if x in features.unique() else 0 for x in total_features]
```

- Using Pandas methods, the result can be achieved with [`.str.fullmatch`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.fullmatch.html):

```py
result = total_features.str.fullmatch('|'.join(features))
```

This will produce a `pd.Series` of booleans, which you can convert to a list of `1`s and `0`s:

```py
result.astype(int).tolist()
```